# deleting row of sqlite database using a button in each row of ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have created a list view which shows the data from a database. In each row of the ListView I have added a CheckBox, a button to delete it and another to edit it. 
My problem is to get the id over the row, in which a button is clicked and how to convert and use that id for my sqlite database command ?
Setting a long click listener has been a bit trouble since the rows do not respond to long click when there is a CheckBox in them , so i want the buttons to exist and function. 
Thanks

Comment: set onClickListener on delete button in getView() method of your Custom Adapter and get the id value by its existing object at specific position given by getView method and use that id to delete the row from database, your table must have unique id in table and your object class should that parameter too, when you populate the ListView from database so that id should also be populated in object class.

Comment: I have implemented the same in my blogpost using SugarORM , http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2016/03/sugar-orm-with-sqlite-android-part-i.html .. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @ShahabRauf , it was very helpful. also thanks to everyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first i describe the structure of the codes and then the solution i found.

the application consist of a main activity which contains the ListView. Then there is a class of SqliteOpenHelper which handles the database and there is a TaskProvider class containing the setter and getter methods of variables in the database and a TaskAdapter which is the custom adapter for the ListView.
The problem that i was facing was the fact that i couldn't address a specific row by a button existed in that row. Here is how i did it :

first in the SqliteOpenHelper class, a method is created to contain the where clause and the SqliteDataBase.delete method

```
public void deleteTask (SQLiteDatabase db , String deleted){
    String selection = Contracts.achieveTaskClass.ID+" LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {deleted};
    db.delete(Contracts.achieveTaskClass.ACHIEVETASK_TABLE,selection,selectionArgs);
}
```

Then in the getView method of adapter class , the button which is set to delete the row is found and the following setOnClickListener is added:

```
objectHolder.taskDeleteButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.list_view_delete_button);
    objectHolder.taskDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String deleted;
            deleted = ((TaskProvider) getItem(position)).getId();
            Sqldb sqldb = new Sqldb(getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = sqldb.getReadableDatabase();
            sqldb.deleteTask(db,deleted);



        }
    });
```